# Visual Studio 2012 "Show All Files" button missing

Tags: visual-studio

In my solution I have three projects: Console application, class library, and a website project. 
The Show All Files button is visible on the console and class library project, but soon as I click on the website project the button disappears.

I am running Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I just got the same problem "Solution Explorer toolbar missing" eg. "Show all files". Here's what I did:

1. Right click your "Solution".
2. Select "New Solution Explorer View". This will pop-up a new "Solution Explorer" window with toolbars in it.
3. Close you original "Solution Explorer" window.

Comment: Interesting.  A new Solution Explorer does come up -- with more buttons in the toolbar than before -- but none of them is "Show All Files" -- (Using VS2013 Premium with update 4) -- I wonder, is there a way to edit this toolbar?

Comment: Won't work for a web site project. See below for answer.

Answer (score 22):

Click on folder which must contain target file and Solution explorer properties will be changed. There you can find Refresh button and Show all files button.

Check this post: 
[Improved Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 to Improve Productivity](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414268/Improved-Solution-Explorer-in-Visual-Studio-2012-t)

Answer (score 16):

"Show All Files" is not shown in a Web Site Project because it's not needed and all files are already shown in the Solution Explorer. I think that this behavior is the same for older versions of VS

Comment: Should of added that my web project didn't show all the files because they were set as hidden in windows. Unhiding the files fixed it.

Comment: So, if we exclude files from the project, we're just stuck seeing them in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @Klay I think that you can't exclude file from the Web Site project, or if you can that will just delete that file.

Comment: @AntonioBakula—did you just try to update your answer? I ask because it [popped up in the review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3757350) as coming from an anonymous user, but it sounds like you wrote it!

Comment: This was the answer for me, if you have multiple projects in your solution, select the non-web project first prior to looking for the button :)

Comment: "Show All Files" can be needed if you exclude something by mistake or need to re-include it.  I would've marked down this answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Solution Explorer, click on a project, and then the 'Show All Files' button will appear.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a WebSite project all files are shown by default. If there are some missing (added during debugging etc), just hit the refresh button on the top of the solution explorer and they should appear.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me.  If this is the case for you try right-clicking on any file in your project, then choosing "Show all files".  The "Show all files" icon should now appear on this and all subsequent Solution Explorer windows.

YMMV, be kind. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The "Show All Files" auto hides.

Click on the folder that has the hidden file, the button should show up.

By clicking on the project (the folder under the solution) the solution explore checks if all sub folders has hidden file, this will prompt the button to be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get Show all file menu just hide the solution explorer and open it fom view=>Other Windows=>Solution Explorer and clik it it will show all files menu

Comment: This worked for me. Except it was just View->Solution Explorer. Not under Other Windows

Answer (score 0):

if you click on solution name in "solution explorer" maybe you will can't see "Show all files" button. because maybe added F# or website project in solution.
if you want see "Show all files" button, you must click on project name which is C# or native C++ or C++.net.

Answer (score -1):

try to open any file use **ctrl+alt+a**  . once a file will open "**show all**" button will appear automatically.