# Opening a Visual Studio 2012 Web Project on another PC

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I copied my project over to another computer to open it and in visual studio and got this error:

```
http://localhost:51278 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:51278. The Web site 'http://localhost:51278' could not be found.
```

I have looked on the link here stated in other answers: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326497

But I fail since I cant find a (Projectname.vbproj.webinfo) File, all I have is a .SLN File.

I set up IIS and dragged the project into the root at (C:\inetpub\wwwroot). Upon opening the file in visual studio I know get this error. Any ideas?

[image]

EDIT:

I ran visual studio as ADMIN and got this error:

```
http://localhost:51278 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:51278. The Web Site 'http://localhost:51278' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server. To open this Web Site, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using this URL from the local IIS web server.
```

Comment: Can you see it if you click the "Show All Files" button in Solution Explorer? (It's at the top)

Comment: Sorry "Show all Files" isn't there for web site projects - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383234/visual-studio-2012-show-all-files-button-missing

Comment: How about right click on .proj file in solution explorer and select "properties" and set the URL there?

Comment: I cant view any files other than the SLN file :/ - I cant even see the code to copy it into a new solution

Comment: @Wazzaday, I'm running into exactly the same issue, any resolution yet?

Comment: Hi Alan, I found that when I moved the project I moved only the visual studio project file (which was just a reference to the code), and not the folder containing all of the actual code. Was a silly mistake