# Update-Database doesn't create db

Tags: asp.net

I have tried to create a db using Update-Database; however, although everything seems to be fine, I don't see any new database created when I click on the SQL Server Object Explorer.

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Stats'.
Using NuGet project 'Stats'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'Stats.DataAccess.StatsDbContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
Applying explicit migrations: [201511280800579_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201511280800579_Initial.
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201511280800579_Initial', N'Stats.Migrations.Configuration',  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

Running Seed method.
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Stats'.
Using NuGet project 'Stats'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'Stats.DataAccess.StatsDbContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM>
```

I don't understand why I am not getting an error message if it's not creating a database. Also, am I supposed to have a connectionStrings element in my config files? It's not there. I thought it was automatically created by default.

Tried to redo every step to no avail:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project Stats.
PM> Add-Migration Initial
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Initial' again.

A previous migration called 'Initial' was already applied to the target database. If you meant to re-scaffold 'Initial', revert it by running 'Update-Database -TargetMigration 201511280718053_Initial', then delete '201511280832547_Initial.cs' and run 'Add-Migration Initial' again.
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201511280832547_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201511280832547_Initial.
Running Seed method.
PM>
```

Comment: trying insert query in new db ?

Comment: Trying to create a new db. I can't find the db. Am I supposed to do something with the config files? In the tutorial I am following the guy doesn't do anything different except it works fine for him.

Comment: If you move your mouse over the icons on the upper right in solution explorer, there should be an icon to show all files. Then, look in the project's App_Data folder.

Comment: I don't see anything like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058093/visual-studio-2013-show-all-files-button-is-missing

Comment: I don't see anything in the App_Data folder. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would normally be a comment, but I'm showing a picture.

If you click on your App_Data folder icon, you will see this icon appear.
Clicking this icon will show/hide certain files in your project.

If there are any files in the folder, they will appear grayed out.
[image: http://itypesetitdesign.com/images/showallfilesicon.jpg]

Since your update-database command ran the seed method, it means that the database exists.

Also, you can look in your sql server's data folder or in the physical app's App_Data folder.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see anything. I clicked on it and then clicked on show all and nothing appears. Even after I open it in File Explorer, I don't see anything.

Comment: When you clicked to show the files, did it put a button (right-facing triangle or plus-sign) in front of the App_Data folder? If it did, then, click it to expand the folder tree.