# How can I add a code-behind file to an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspx-user-control

There are two pages in a legacy app to which I'm addding fuctionality.

One of the .aspx files, when the "Design" view is shown, sports an Events tab in the Properties pane:

[image]

The other, though, does not - it only shows Properties:

[image]

I need to add a custom method to this code; how can I create a corresponding .vb code-behind file where I can add this method?

### UPDATE

I tried jackjop's suggestions, but F7 did nothing, and I do not seem to have the "Show All Files" glyph:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

I tried adding this to the top of the .aspx file, mirroring what is in the aspx/aspx.vb pair that works as I want, but it didn't seem to make any difference:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="custmaint_entry.aspx.vb" Inherits="pages_custmaint_entry" %>
```

Comment: hmm, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058093/visual-studio-2013-show-all-files-button-is-missing) can help

Comment: You can delete the .aspx page, then re-add it, making sure this time to choose the one that adds the code behind. Then copy your markup back into the .aspx, making sure not to erase the code behind related stuff in the @Page directive. Alternatively, create a text file manually and then include it in your project. If VS doesn't automatically nest it you can modify the .vbproj, following the format of the other code behinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an ASPX file it also creates a code-behind file. You just can't see it.

From aspx file press F7 or click `Show All Files` button in Solution Explorer.

[image]

Notice that when `Show All Files` is not clicked, it doesn't show code behind files.

[image]

Or you can just simply right-click on aspx file on `Solution Explorer` and click `View Code`. If this also does not work, then you probably deleted the code behind files, I suggest you re-creating every file.

Comment: You can *normally* see it, so this will only be useful if the code behind has been excluded from the project, which is possible but unlikely.

Comment: Nope, sometimes even if it is included, it doesn't show up on Solution Explorer

Comment: Please see Update.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the solution was created from a precompiled and deployed application and the code behind files do not get deployed. I can also see many "Copy of" files littering the solution.

I am posting because this is typical in many legacy applications -- the original source code needs to be located -- you cannot modify precompiled code without the source. (Well, you *can* however you will have to rewrite ALL of the code behind and other custom DLLs). And **NO**, a "decompiler" is of no use here.

This is what I am doing on my own legacy code, but -- it is a piecemeal task and whether it is better than starting all over is debatable. Unfortunately, the real fix would be for enterprises to maintain a full source code repository.