# I do not know what is app_data in .net web application?how do we find it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I do not know what is app_data in .net web application?how do we find it? is it default or we create it. When I opened a new project I am not able to see it

Comment: What is the version of Visual studio you are using?

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP and a Google search would have took less than half the time to answer your question - https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20app_data

Comment: I was able to create app_data folder in the project but it is not visible after I closed the application and opened again. How do i view APP_DATA?

Answer (score 1):

The App_Data folder is used by ASP.Net applications. It is primarily used to store a local database or other data files such as XML files. For more information see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks!I was able to create app_data folder in the project but it is not visible after I closed the application and opened again. How do i view APP_DATA?

Comment: @divya You have to click Show All ltems in Solution Explorer ToolBar to see all hidden folders and files. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18040675/379855

Answer (score 0):

[What is the App_Data folder used for in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio)

To make it easier to work with your application, ASP.NET reserves certain file and folder names that you can use for specific types of content. App_Data contains application data files including .mdf database files, XML files, and other data store files.

Comment: Thanks!I was able to create app_data folder in the project but it is not visible after I closed the application and opened again. How do i view APP_DATA?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem finding no app_data after create a web project. My solution is to use the web-form template instead of empty template and then the VS will create the folder for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the new project as ASP.NET Web Application(.Net Framework) not ASP.Net Core Web Application. then Visual studio will automatically create the App_Data folder for you.

See the project templates

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This cannot be the answer because core was release on 27 June 2016, which was after the question was asked! (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core)

Comment: I agree with you in this context. But nowadays people are getting this error because of this protect template change.